# Test input value against RegExp as an HTML5 fallback

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm writing a small fallback for HTML5 input type 'email' validation that will alert the user if the email is invalid. [For older browsers, the script will set 'data' to the relevant inputs, and my script below picks up the 'email' part of the data]. I'm not sure how to set this RegExp test up entirely to find the outcome.

Here's what I have so far (this is inside an $.each loop), I basically want to include a RegExp test inside an 'if' statement, and prevent the form from submitting if the email address provided doesn't support the RegExp. Also, I know it's not amazing to test emails via RegExp, but this is provided from the W3C as a fallback solution and our team have decided to go with it.

```
/*
 * Email fallback
 */
var self = $(this)
var emailFallback = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

if ( self.data('fallback') === 'email' ) {

    var str = self.val()

    console.log(str.test(emailFallback))
    return str.test(emailFallback)

    // prevent submission
    event.preventDefault()

}
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What about [domains with non-ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)? They can be translated to ASCII – but the users won't enter them like that.

Comment: I'm unsure of your question and desired solution.  Your message uses terms like HTML5 and RegEx but your tags say jQuery and validation.  While these work together, they can lead to different solutions.

Comment: I thought tags were to show the relevance/category of my post, not the tech I want the solution to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you have the correct logic, but you rather test a string from a regEx:

```
emailFallback .test(str);
```

I've done a pretty similar thing in one web application. If html5 is supported, I've added a pattern attribute to the inputs, which will serve as a regex itself, without JS. If html5 is not supported, I added the same regex as an alt attribute and checked it while typing or bluring on input fields.

One part of the code:

```
strictNum.each(function() {
                    var el = $(this);

                    if (html5) {
                        el.get(0).type = 'text';
                        el.attr('pattern', '[\\d]+');
                        el.attr('required', 'required');

                        if (el.is('#edit-submitted-zahlverfahren-bankleitzahl')) el.attr('pattern', '^(\\d){8}$');
                    }
                    else {
                        el.attr('alt', '[\\d]+');
                        if (el.is('#edit-submitted-zahlverfahren-bankleitzahl')) el.attr('alt', '^(\\d){8}$');
                    }

                    el.bind('keyup', function() {
                        var     v = el.val();

                        if ( v.match(/[\d]/gi) !== null && v.length && v.match(/[\d]/gi).length !== v.length ) el.val( el.val().replace(/[^\d]/gi, '') );
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Cool stuff Alex, though I think using 'alt' is abusing semantics a little. Perhaps a 'data-pattern' attribute is best suited, that's where I'm going with this project! I've changed 'test' to match, and using if(str.match(emailFallback)) {...} and it works! Is that what you intended? :)

Comment: well, you dont need to use match, I just had to check while typing. You can go like if (/myregex/.test(str) ) {..} else .. and yes, using the data attribute would be better, indeed. good point!

Comment: So how is match similar to test? regex.test(string) or string.match(regex) both work. And glad I could return the helpfulness :)

Comment: no theyre not at all! just google for what each one does ;) in your case .test() is better, because .match() returns an array/ strings of those parts that actually match a regex while test just returns true/ false if it does or does not ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks Alex. Have a great night and thanks for the homework :)